# Cannot resolve method 'AddSnapshotListener (Firebase.firestore method)

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm running a project on Android Studio and using Firestore,so i'm building the "Feed"(Show all the recipes) and got a weird error regarding AddSnapshotListener method from Firestore

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    recipeRef.addSnapshotListener(this, new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                return;
            }

            String data = "";

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                RecipeC recipe = documentSnapshot.toObject(RecipeC.class);
                recipe.setTitle(documentSnapshot.getId());

                String rtitle = recipe.getRtitle();
                String rclass = recipe.getRclass();
                String body = recipe.getBody();
                String publisher = recipe.getPublisher();



                data += "Titulo: " + rtitle + "\nClase: " + rclass + "\nCuerpo: " + body + "\nPublicador:" + publisher;
            }

            textViewfdata.setText(data);
        }
    });
}
```

This was shown when completing my data query and AS can't recognize recipe object from RecipeC.

I'll attach my RecipeC Java Class

```
package com.sergioa.ut.test;
public class RecipeC {
    String rtitle;
    String body;
    String rclass;
    String publisher;

    public RecipeC(){

    }

    public RecipeC(String rtitle, String rclass, String body, String publisher) {
        this.rtitle = rtitle;
        this.rclass = rclass;
        this.body = body;
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }


    public String getRtitle() { return rtitle; }

    public void setTitle(String rtitle) { this.rtitle = rtitle; }

    public String getBody() { return body; }

    public void setBody(String body) { this.body= body; }

    public String getRclass() { return rclass; }

    public void setRclass(String rclass) { this.rclass = rclass; }

    public String getPublisher() { return publisher; }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) { this.publisher = publisher; }
}
```

`

Comment: How have you initialised the `recipeRef` object? Please also add the contant of your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: I got rid of the error calling correctly to the class in every string ,i noticed them weren't as the name of the object recipe on RecipeC as it shown. `RecipeC recipe = documentSnapshot.toObject(RecipeC.class);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the error calling correctly to the class in every string ,i noticed them weren't as the name of the object recipe on RecipeC as it shown. RecipeC recipe = documentSnapshot.toObject(RecipeC.class);